# Reshuffle data evenly across Cassandra ring

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.1

I have three-node ring of Apache Cassandra 2.1.12. I inserted some data when it was 2-node ring and then added one more `172.16.5.54` node in the ring. I am using the vnode in my ring. The problem is data is not distributed evenly where as ownership seems distributed evenly. So, how to redistribute the data aross the ring. I have tried with `nodetool repair` and `nodetool cleanup` but still no luck.

Moreover, what does this load and own column signify in the `nodetool status` output. 
Also, If out of these three-node if i import the data from one of the node from the file. So, CPU utilization goes upto 100% and finally data on the rest of the two nodes get distributed evenly but not on import running node. Why is it so?

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
    =======================
    Status=Up/Down
    |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
    --  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
    UN  172.16.5.54   1.47 MB    256     67.4%             40d07f44-eef8-46bf-9813-4155ba753370  rack1
    UN  172.16.4.196  165.65 MB  256     68.3%             6315bbad-e306-4332-803c-6f2d5b658586  rack1
    UN  172.16.3.172  64.69 MB   256     64.4%             26e773ea-f478-49f6-92a5-1d07ae6c0f69  rack1
```

Comment: I think you'll need to run `nodetool cleanup` as well. [Docs are here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCleanup.html). "Use this command to remove unwanted data after adding a new node to the cluster."

Comment: @LHWizard doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 1):

The columns in the output are explained for cassandra 2.1.x [in this doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsStatus.html). The load is the amount of file system data in the cassandra data directories. It seems unbalanced across your 3 nodes, which might imply that your partition keys are clustering on a single node (172.16.4.196), sometimes called a hot spot.

The Owns column is "the percentage of the data owned by the node per datacenter times the replication factor." So I can deduce your RF=2 because each node Owns roughly 2/3 of the data.

Answer (score -1):

You need to fix your partition keys of tables.

Cassandra distributes the data based on partition keys to nodes (using hash partitioning range).
So, for some reason you have alot of data for few partition key value, and almost non for rest partition key values.